# NSUserDefault not being saved

Tags: ios, swift, nsuserdefaults, uialertview

I only want the alert to show up if the variable "genderDefault" has not been assigned yet.

This code is suppose to save the choice of the user:

```
func genderAlert()
    {
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Quick Question", message: "What's your gender?", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
        let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Male", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default) {
        UIAlertAction in
        NSLog("Male Pressed")
            self.genderDefault.setValue("male", forKey: "gender")
        }
        let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Female", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default) {
        UIAlertAction in
        NSLog("Female Pressed")
            self.genderDefault.setValue("female", forKey: "gender")
        }
        alertController.addAction(okAction)
        alertController.addAction(cancelAction)
        self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

This is the if-statement that controls whether the alert shows up:

```
if(genderDefault != "male" || genderDefault != "female")
        {
            genderAlert()
        }
```

Comment: What is `genderDefault`?  When you set it, you treat it like a dictionary. When you test it, you treat it like a string. You need to show more code. Also, in your if you want an and `&&` since it can't be both male and female at the same time. Or you can use == instead of != with or ||

Comment: How would you fix genderDefault.  I don't  use it anywhere else. @Paulw11

Comment: I don't think it is broken. I think your if logic is broken, but you haven't shown where these variables come from or get their values since you haven't shown that code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Swift 3**

```
let genderDefault = UserDefaults.standard
genderDefault.set(value: AnyObject?, forKey: String) // SET
genderDefault.object(forKey: String)                 // GET
```

**Swift 2**

```
let genderDefault = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
genderDefault.setObject("female", forKey: "gender")    // SET
if let gender = genderDefault.stringForKey("gender"){  // GET
    if((gender as! String) != "male" || (gender as! String) != "female")
    {
        genderAlert()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What ever you do you have to set userDefaults.synchronize() at last so that userDefaults should come to know that now it has to save

```
let userDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
userDefaults.setValue("female", forKey: "gender")
userDefaults.synchronize() // don't forget this!!!!
```

Comment: `.synchronize` is not necessary anymore.

Comment: Ok, i prefer using it :)